# ice:panelPopup waits for user action

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I must make validations to the data that the user enters and if a validation does not pass, it must show a popup where the user is asked if he wants to use that data or cancel. The popup has two options (yes or no).

I need the next validation to wait for the user's response before executing.
The problem is that the other validations continue without waiting for the user's response.

I'm developing with java 1.6 and icefaces 1.8.2, using ice: panelpopup for the dialog.

Here is a part of panelpopup code:

```
<ice:form>
    <ice:panelPopup id="popupBeanValidarFecha" draggable="true"
                    resizable="false" style="width: 400px; 
                    max-width: 400px; height: 150px;"
                    visible="#{popupBeanValidarFecha.visible}"
                    rendered="#{popupBeanValidarFecha.visible}" 
                    modal="true">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <ice:panelGrid width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
            style="text-align: center;" headerClass="icePanelPopupHeader">
                <ice:outputText style="color: #FFFFFF;" value="Mensaje" />
            </ice:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>

        <f:facet name="body">
            <ice:panelGrid width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
            style="text-align: center;">
                <ice:outputLabel style="FONT-WEIGHT: bold;"
                value="#{popupBeanValidarFecha.mensaje}" />
                <br />
                <div align="center">
                    <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <ice:commandButton value="Si" partialSubmit="true" 
                        action="#{popupBeanValidarFecha.aceptar}" title="Si"
                        visible="true" rendered="true" />
                        <ice:commandButton value="No" partialSubmit="true"
                        action="#{popupBeanValidarFecha.cancelar}" title="No"
                        visible="true" rendered="true" />
                    </ice:panelGrid>
                </div>
            </ice:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>
    </ice:panelPopup>
</ice:form>
```

Comment: Upvote for PanelPooUp

Comment: @SteveSmith: it is indeed funny, and you can propose an edit of it... Every 'accepted' edit gains you 2 reputation